# Drawing tool used in Mercurial tutorial

Tags: drawing

I'm needing to do some screen layout proposals, and really like the look of the pictures used in Joel's Mercurial tutorial, example here:
http://hginit.com/01.html

Can someone enlighten me on what tool(s) will generate this kind of output?

I guess a related question would be if people have a favorite screen mock up tool?  It's not a requirement for me that the mockup be "functional".

Thanks!
Mike

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like [balsamiq](http://balsamiq.com/) to me; the Comic Sans is a dead giveaway...

Edit: I’ve used balsamiq for screen mock-ups, and it’s very good.  The only downside is that it is not free.  And it uses Comic sans! ;)

Comment: Sebastien, I think you are right!  I'm very impressed that it took less than 2 minutes to get the answer!

Comment: Comic Sans always sticks out like a sore thumb.

Comment: @Maxpm: Tell me about it.  I think that’s why balsamiq is so vivid in my memory...  :)

Comment: I wonder if we'll ever be able to get rid of it :/

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Sébastien, but would like to point out that **[Pencil](http://pencil.evolus.vn/en-US/Home.aspx)** might enable you to produce similar-looking mockups.

Comment: I think Sebastien is right about the product Joel used, but I agree that Pencil also looks like it would do what I need. I'll install them both and try them out "head to head".  Thanks everyone!  Mike

Answer (score 0):

this looks like [toolbar buttons used in the command line window](https://mockupstogo.mybalsamiq.com/projects/desktopapplications/IBM%20AS%20400%205250%20Emulator)

it took me a sec to realize you have to set the window widget's properties to display the buttons as shown to get them to show up

[image]